# angular.js textarea character count to exclude counting spaces and newline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

My textarea field needs to count the characters to display number of characters remaining against the maxlength defined.
But the count goes wrong when spaces/newline characters are entered by user or when text is pasted from elsewhere.

I need to know if angular has any directive or a way to support the exclusion of space/newline counted.

```
<textarea class="form-control"  maxlength="{{desc}}" my-maxlength = "{{desc}}" maxlen="maxlen" type="text" ng-model="problem.DESCRIPTION" aria-describedby="qDesc" id="questionDescription" name="questionDescription" ng-required="caseType" lang-check></textarea>
<p ng-show="problem.DESCRIPTION.length > (desc-5)" class="text-danger pull-right" id="qDesc">{{ desc - problem.DESCRIPTION.length}} {{ resource["textcount.sublabel.maximumcharacters"] }</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a filter to return the number of non-whitespace characters

```
yourModule.filter('charCount', function() {
    return function(text) {
        return (text.match(/\S/g) || []).length;
    };
})
```

and use that in your template

```
problem.DESCRIPTION | charCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ***angularjs*** solution you need, try to use

> ng-trim="false"

in ***textarea***. Here is the example

```
<body ng-app>
   <textarea ng-model="test" ng-trim="false" maxlength="1500"></textarea>
   <span>{{1500 - test.length}} left</span>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't see how this is going to help OP to *"support the exclusion of space/newline counted"*

Answer (score -1):

You can't just run `problem.DESCRIPTION.length` in `ng-show` or in `{{}}`, it won't run, you have to create a function and insert in `ng-show` or `{{}}`

In your controller create a function to remove white spaces of a string and return its length

**JS:**

```
$scope.countLength = function(str){
    if (str==undefined){
        return 0;                    
    }
    else{
        return str.replace(/ /g,'', '').length;  
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p ng-show="countLength(problem.DESCRIPTION) > (desc-5)" class="text-danger pull-right" 
id="qDesc">{{ desc - countLength(problem.DESCRIPTION)}} 
{{ resource["textcount.sublabel.maximumcharacters"] }</p>
```

Look at the example here:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azd1og0j/1/)